# MVC Access stored cookie

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies

I want a dropdown on a page, WHere i can select some currency value to display.

And then, on **any** page, I can access the value that was selected, via the **use of cookies**.

However, I only seem able to access the cookie (Display on screen), if it was posted. Else **refreshing the page, it is blank**.

What am i doing wrong?

Controller

```
public ActionResult CurrencySelection()
    {
        Response.Cookies.Add(Request.Cookies["Currency"]);
        return PartialView();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CurrencySelection(String currencySelection)
    {
        HttpCookie fc = new HttpCookie("Currency", currencySelection);
        Response.Cookies.Add(fc);

        return PartialView();
    }
```

my View/ Helper:

```
@{
    String currency = Response.Cookies["Currency"].Value;

    @("CURRENCY: " + currency)    
}

  @using (Ajax.BeginForm("CurrencySelection", "Header", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "currencySelectionDiv" }))
 {      
    <select name="currencySelection">
      <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
      <option value="DKK">DKK</option>
      <option value="SEK">SEK</option>
      <option value="EURO">EURO</option>
    </select>

    <input  type="submit" value="Update" id="submit" />   
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to persist the cookie when you change selection without having to manually select "submit"?

Comment: @James No, I guess the better way to phrase it is: `How do I access cookie Value from my View?` Without the controller doing anything with the cookie at all. Aka, the view accesses what is stored already. I assumed this would, but i wasnt sure if i was blanking it some how.

Answer (score 2):

In order to read a cookie client-side it needs to be created with the [HttpOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.httponly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) flag set to `false`. Assuming you initially create the cookie server-side then your code would look like

```
HttpCookie fc = new HttpCookie("Currency", currencySelection);
fc.HttpOnly = false; // enable client-side access
Response.Cookies.Add(fc);
```

This means in your view, without any server-side interaction, you can query for that cookie value by parsing [document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie) property using Javascript. In terms of parsing the cookie, there are tons of examples online, and infact, there is a good little utility supplied in the documentation - see [A little framework: a complete cookies reader/writer with full unicode support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie#A_little_framework.3A_a_complete_cookies_reader.2Fwriter_with_full_unicode_support)