# How create view for show cookie's info in asp.net mvc using razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, cookies, model, viewmodel

I'm developing  an online store using `asp.net mvc 5` and I used `cookie` for add goods to cart . I want to have a page to show selected items (in cookie) and I don't know how do it, I just wrote an action result for it named `Basket` . I should use `@model List<BasketVM>` in my view but when don't know how ?!

could anyone help me please ?
Thanks

**GoodController**

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Basket()
    {
        GoodDetailsRepositories blGoodDetails = new GoodDetailsRepositories();
        List<BasketVM> listBasket = new List<BasketVM>();
        List<HttpCookie> lst = new List<HttpCookie>();
        for (int i = Request.Cookies.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (lst.Where(p => p.Name == Request.Cookies[i].Name).Any() == false)
                lst.Add(Request.Cookies[i]);
        }
        foreach (var item in lst.Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("NishtmanCart_")))
        {
            listBasket.Add(new BasketVM {
                GoodDetails = blGoodDetails.Find(Convert.ToInt32(item.Name.Substring(13))), Count =Convert.ToInt32(item.Value) });
        }
        return View(listBasket);
    }
```

**BasketVM.cs**

```
 public class BasketVM
{
    public NP1.Models.GoodDetail GoodDetails { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

**GoodDetails.cs**

```
public partial class GoodDetail
{
    public GoodDetail()
    {
        this.FactorItems = new HashSet<FactorItem>();
    }

    public int DetailsGoodID { get; set; }
    public int FKSubGoods { get; set; }
    public string NishtmanCode { get; set; }
    public string DetailsColor { get; set; }
    public string DetailsExist { get; set; }
    public long DetailsNowPrice { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> DetailsPrePrice { get; set; }
    public string DetailsName { get; set; }
    public string DetailsLeatherType { get; set; }
    public string DetailsWeight { get; set; }
    public string DetailsSize { get; set; }
    public string DetailsProducer { get; set; }
    public string DetailsExtraInfo { get; set; }
    public string DetailsURL { get; set; }
    public string DetailsKeyWords { get; set; }
    public string DetailsTags { get; set; }
    public int DetailsLike { get; set; }
    public int DetailsDisLike { get; set; }
    public string DetailsImage1 { get; set; }
    public string DetailsSmallImage1 { get; set; }
    public string DetailsImage2 { get; set; }
    public string DetailsSmallImage2 { get; set; }
    public string DetailsImage3 { get; set; }
    public string DetailsSmallImage3 { get; set; }
    public string DetailsImage4 { get; set; }
    public string DetailsSmallImage4 { get; set; }

    public virtual SubGood SubGood { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FactorItem> FactorItems { get; set; }
}
```

**Add to cart code**

```
public ActionResult AddToCart (int Id , int Count)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("NishtmanCart_" + Id.ToString()))
        {
            //Edit cookie
            var cookie = new HttpCookie("NishtmanCart_" + Id.ToString(), (Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["NishtmanCart_" + Id.ToString()].Value) + 1).ToString());
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
            cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);

        }
        else
        {
            //Add new cookie
            var cookie = new HttpCookie("NishtmanCart_" + Id.ToString(), Count.ToString());
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
            cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
            List<HttpCookie> lst = new List<HttpCookie>();
            for (int i = 0; i < Request.Cookies.Count; i++ )
            {
                lst.Add(Request.Cookies[i]);
            }

            bool isGet = Request.HttpMethod == "GET";
            int CartCount = lst.Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("NishtmanCart_") && p.HttpOnly != isGet).Count();
            return Json(new MyJsonData()
            {
                Success = true,
                Script = MessageBox.Show("Good added successfully", MessageType.Success).Script,

                Html = "cart items (" + CartCount.ToString() + ")"
            }
                );
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            return Json(new MyJsonData()
            {
                Success = false,

                Script = "alert('Good didn't add');",
                Html = ""
            }
                );

        }

    }
```

Comment: I updated my post dear @Anonymous

Comment: So what's the better way for do this ? I want to show some number of `GoodDetails` fields and related cookie . I mean number of cart items . @Anonymous

Comment: Your structure is well and good but you can store these thing in session. As item gets added or deleted or updated, session can easily be modified

Comment: You're right , but if I use session, users should sign-up first then they can do the shopping ? That's right ? @Anonymous

Comment: Not necessary, session can be maintained without any login

Comment: Or I can solve your issue if you can tell me what you are getting in list before passing to view

Comment: Sorry , you mean this ? `return View(listBasket);` @Anonymous

Comment: I am asking for value of listBasket only

Comment: listbasket contains GoodDetails , I posted all of my codes dear @Anonymous sorry my English is not good

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100951/discussion-between-anonymous-and-shima-amini).

Answer (score 0):

with what name you are saving the cookies you can retrieve like this let say userid u want to get rest what you have wriiten will work:

```
    if (this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("Userid"))
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Userid"];
        // retrieve cookie data here
    }

how to call in view :

Viewbag.userid = @Request.Cookies["Userid"].value

In order to read a cookie client-side it needs to be created with the HttpOnly flag set to false.
Please go thorugh the below already asked question.
```

[MVC Access stored cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657938/mvc-access-stored-cookie)

Comment: Thank you dear , but also I don't know how create view for show it

Comment: and could you please write an example of showing `retrieve cookie data` ?!